# How do i convert an arbitrary duration(time format(HMS)) into minutes in R?

Tags: r, date, time, datetime-format

I have a character vector of the form

```
duration <- c("57M8S","31S","2H20M31S", "21M32S")
```

I want to convert all of the vector into minutes, so that I get a result like

```
c(57.13, 0.52, 140.52, 21.53)
```

How will I do so ?
I tried using `strsplit(duration,[A-Z])`, this gives me a list of character vectors.
But this has uneven number of elements.
Can somebody please guide me.

Comment: Your question title and main body seem to disagree. Not all of your entries are of the form `HMS`. Also `c(57M8S,31S,2H20M31S, 21M32S)` is not a character vector; do you mean something like this `c("57M8S","31S","2H20M31S", "21M32S")`?

Comment: Yeah that's what i meant. Sorry for not explaining the question properly.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```
duration <- c("57M8S","31S","2H20M31S", "21M32S")

sapply(duration, function(x) {
    v <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x, "[HMS]")));
    return(sum(60^(rev(seq_along(v) - 2)) * v));
})
#     57M8S         31S    2H20M31S      21M32S
#57.1333333   0.5166667 140.5166667  21.5333333
```

Explanation: Split entries on any `HMS` character; then multiply each value with `60^k`, where the exponent `k` is given by the number of split values minus `2`. So if we end up with only one value after the split, the value denotes seconds, and we multiply this entry with `60^(-1)` to convert to minutes.

---

Or to demonstrate more explicitly (and more awkwardly):

```
sapply(duration, function(x) {
    v <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x, "[HMS]")));
    if (length(v) == 1) val <- v / 60;
    if (length(v) == 2) val <- v[1] + v[2] / 60;
    if (length(v) == 3) val <- v[1] * 60 + v[2] + v[3] / 60;
    return(val);
})
```

---

Another interesting approach from @akrun uses package `gsubfn` to replace `H` with `* 60 +`, `M` with `* 1 +` and `S` with `* 1/60 +`, before `eval`uating the resulting string:

```
library(gsubfn);
sapply(sub(
    " \\+$", "", 
        gsubfn("([HMS])", list(H = "* 60 +",M = "* 1 +", S = "* 1/60 +"), duration)), 
    function(x) eval(parse(text= x)))
#    57* 1 +8* 1/60               31* 1/60 2* 60 +20* 1 +31* 1/60
#        57.1333333              0.5166667            140.5166667
#   21* 1 +32* 1/60
#        21.5333333
```

Comment: Another option is `gsubfn` `sapply(sub(" \\+$", "",  gsubfn("([HMS])",  list(H = "* 60 +",M = "* 1 +", S = "* 1/60 +"), duration)), function(x) eval(parse(text= x)))`

Comment: Nice approach @akrun! I'll add unless you want to post as separate answer.

Comment: Sure, you can add it. Thanks